# Strange behavior of preg_match for dashes and underscores

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have following two expressions. both are almost same, in first i check the string ending with 3 dashes and in second ending with 3 underscores

```
$str="this-is_normal-test---";
$str= preg_match("/[a-zA-z0-9]+(-+)$/",$str,$matches);
print_r($matches);

$str="this-is_normal-test___";
$str= preg_match("/[a-zA-z0-9]+(_+)$/",$str,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Here is the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test---
    [1] => ---
)
Array
(
    [0] => test___
    [1] => _
)
```

The problem is, the first one shows all the three matched dashes and the second one shows only one underscore matched. why? What is the logic/happening for this weird behavior ?

Answer (score 4):

In US-ASCII (and most derived encodings), the `[A-z]` range includes `_` but not `-`:

```
echo implode('', range('A', 'z'));
```

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

I suppose it's a typo and you really mean:

```
'/[a-z0-9]+(-+)$/i'
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand why this fixes it, but it's because you have `A-z`, not `A-Z`, so:

```
$str= preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(_+)$/",$str,$matches); //note uppercase Z
```

I can only assume that in ascertaining all characters between `A-z` (lowercase Z) it seems to include underscores, an alphanumeric character.

Comment: a-zA-A0-9 should probably be a-zA-Z0-9

Comment: Seems to work indeed. Maybe between capital A en lowercase z there is a underscore.